# How to get params in a model?

Tags: grails, model

How to get params in a model (in Grails) ? `params.` does not exist in a model.

Comment: There are a few ways to get http parameters inside a domain object, but all of them are hacks. How do you plan to use this and why standard ways doesn't work for you?

Comment: I simply want to avoid to pass ALL params or EACH ONE I NEED by hand to the model/domain model. Problem is: When you build the model data you often need params, and handling them in the controller is annoying sometimes (even it's correct to the MVC structure).

Comment: you can pass it as a object, you don't need to pass each one. why not?

Answer (score 4):

If by "Model" you mean a Domain Model class, they don't have params, they're just POJOs. Params only apply to Controllers, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a special method for filling domain from request. At this case you could pass all params (it's a Map) to such method, like:

```
def MyDomain {

  static MyDomain buildFromParams(def params) {
     return new MyDomain(
         field1: params.field_1, //assuming that your params have different naming scheme so you can't use standard way suggested by Raphael
         field2: params.field_2
     )
  }

}

class MyController {

  def myAction() {
     MyDomain foo = MyDomain.buildFromParams(params)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your parameter names are propertly formated and match the domain attributes, you can do this:

Assuming

```
params = [name:"some name", age: "194", civilState: "MARRIED"]
```

and

```
class Person{
   String name
   Integer age
   CivilStatus civilState //some enum
}
```

You can leverage groovy's property binding constructor like this in a controller:

```
class Controller {
   def saveAction = {
       new Person(params)
   }
}
```